# Can't convert expression to float - using sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have this code below but I have ran into an error and am unsure what to do. I have tried changing the dtype on the arrays but that doesn't work either.

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import transpose
from numpy import array
from numpy import sum
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def equations():
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')

    f_xyz_1 = 15*a + b**2 - 4*c - 15
    f_xyz_2 = a**2 + 10*b - c - 10 
    f_xyz_3 = b**3 - 25*c + 24

    return [f_xyz_1, f_xyz_2, f_xyz_3]

def f_bold(x):
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')
    vals = {a: x[0], b: x[1], c: x[2]}

    f_new_1 = equations()[0].subs(vals)
    f_new_2 = equations()[1].subs(vals)
    f_new_3 = equations()[2].subs(vals)    
    return array([[f_new_1], [f_new_2], [f_new_3]], dtype='float64')

def f(x):
    f_n = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        f_i = f_bold(x)[i]**2
        f_n.append(f_i)

    return sum(f_n)

def M(x):
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')
    vals = {a: x[0], b: x[1], c: x[2]}

    f_xyz_1_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[0], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_1_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[0], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_1_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[0], c).subs(vals)

    f_xyz_2_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[1], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_2_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[1], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_2_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[1], c).subs(vals)

    f_xyz_3_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[2], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_3_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[2], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_3_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[2], c).subs(vals)

    return array([[f_xyz_1_diff_x, f_xyz_2_diff_x, f_xyz_3_diff_x], [f_xyz_1_diff_y, f_xyz_2_diff_y, f_xyz_3_diff_y], [f_xyz_1_diff_z, f_xyz_2_diff_z, f_xyz_3_diff_z]], dtype='float64')

def grad_f(x):
    return 2*np.dot(M(x), f_bold(x))

def d(x):
    return -1*grad_f(x)/norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)

def s_prime(x, alpha, d):
    return np.dot(transpose(grad_f(x + alpha*d)))

x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
alpha = 0.75
print(s_prime(x, alpha, d(x)))
```

When I print s_prime, it prints the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method for three equations.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(s_prime(x, alpha, d(x)))
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method for three equations.py", line 60, in s_prime
    return np.dot(transpose(grad_f(x + alpha*d)))
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method for three equations.py", line 54, in grad_f
    return 2*np.dot(M(x), f_bold(x))
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method for three equations.py", line 51, in M
    return array([[f_xyz_1_diff_x, f_xyz_2_diff_x, f_xyz_3_diff_x], [f_xyz_1_diff_y, f_xyz_2_diff_y, f_xyz_3_diff_y], [f_xyz_1_diff_z, f_xyz_2_diff_z, f_xyz_3_diff_z]], dtype='float64')
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 327, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

But when I print the other defs, it doesn't print any errors.

Comment: What happens if you print out the variables `f_xyz_1_diff_x`, `f_xyz_1_diff_y`, etc., inside your function `M(x)`?

Comment: It's fine, it prints out the numbers

Comment: I made a mistake with s_prime and missed out the second argument (d) for transpose, but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried printing out the numbers myself, and sometimes it still prints out symbolic expressions. I'd recheck the print statements that you added to `M(x)`. (You did add print statements to the definition of `M(x)`, right?)

Comment: Yes, I did. I printed out the array of M(x) and they're all numbers, not symbolic expressions.

Comment: They're still symbolic expressions in the code you showed here. The last row of the array that `M(x)` is supposed to return is `[[15, 2*x, 0], [2*y, 10, 3*y**2], [-4, -1, -25]]`. FYI, what I did was change `M(x)` so that what was originally the first argument of `array` was assigned to `out_arr`, and the return statement was then changed to `return array(out_arr, dtype='float64')`. Before the return statement, I added the statement `print(out_arr)`.

Comment: Ah ok, I assigned values to the symbols, so that's probably why I didn't get symbolic expressions. But I still have the issue with s_prime def.

Comment: The traceback indicates that your problems are in the `M(x)` function itself. The TypeError exception comes from `array()` attempting and failing to convert the elements in its first argument to floating-point numbers.

Comment: So I have added the out_arr to the defs, and obviously, d(x) doesn't work (it works if I assign numerical values to the symbols). But s_prime(x) still doesn't work, even if I assign values.

Comment: `dot(transpose(...))` is a wrong call to `dot`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I have solved the problem; the x array was not the right shape. I will upload the correct code momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import transpose
from numpy import array
from numpy import sum
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def equations():
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')

    f_xyz_1 = 15*a + b**2 - 4*c - 15
    f_xyz_2 = a**2 + 10*b - c - 10 
    f_xyz_3 = b**3 - 25*c + 24

    return [f_xyz_1, f_xyz_2, f_xyz_3]

def f_bold(x):
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')
    vals = {a: x[0][0], b: x[1][0], c: x[2][0]}

    f_new_1 = equations()[0].subs(vals)
    f_new_2 = equations()[1].subs(vals)
    f_new_3 = equations()[2].subs(vals)

    out_arr = [[f_new_1], [f_new_2], [f_new_3]]

    return array(out_arr, dtype='float32')

def f(x):
    f_n = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        f_i = f_bold(x)[i]**2
        f_n.append(f_i)

    return sum(f_n)

def M(x):
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('x y z')
    vals = {a: x[0][0], b: x[1][0], c: x[2][0]}

    f_xyz_1_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[0], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_1_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[0], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_1_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[0], c).subs(vals)

    f_xyz_2_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[1], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_2_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[1], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_2_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[1], c).subs(vals)

    f_xyz_3_diff_x = sym.diff(equations()[2], a).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_3_diff_y = sym.diff(equations()[2], b).subs(vals)
    f_xyz_3_diff_z = sym.diff(equations()[2], c).subs(vals)

    out_arr = [[f_xyz_1_diff_x, f_xyz_2_diff_x, f_xyz_3_diff_x], [f_xyz_1_diff_y, f_xyz_2_diff_y, f_xyz_3_diff_y], [f_xyz_1_diff_z, f_xyz_2_diff_z, f_xyz_3_diff_z]]

    return array(out_arr, dtype='float32')

def grad_f(x):
    return 2*np.dot(M(x), f_bold(x))

def d(x):
    return -1*grad_f(x)/norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)

def s_prime(x, alpha, d):
    return np.dot(transpose(grad_f(x + alpha*d)), d)

x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
x = np.reshape(x, (3, 1))
alpha = 0.75
d_k = d(x)

print(s_prime(x, alpha, d_k))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).